# Using UNC path with psexec does not work in remote connection

Tags: networking, unc, psexec

Hi I am trying to open a setup file in serverB in serverA that I am connecting to remotely. When I use the UNC path for folder in serverB the error message states that the network path is not found. I know that there is some security layer that is preventing me from doing this. I tried to map network drive n use that to open the installer but same error message comes up. This is the code. What is preventing me from opening this file? My guess is because I am double hopping is there credssp in psexec like in powershell that enables double hopping?

```
psexec -s \\serverA -u xxxlab\xx004 -p xxxxx -i 0 -d "\\serverB\npp.6.3.3.Installer.exe"
```

Comment: So what exactly is that `0` in between -i and -d? I don't recall that being a parameter.

Comment: Its for session without it that command still fails me and adding -h doesn't help either